# Filling list (as an array) : without cut, backtracking leads to infinite recursion after giving a correct production

Tags: prolog, prolog-cut

I need to initialize some lists with a finite number of elements, all the same.

```
fill( 0, [], _ ) :- !.
fill( Index, [Value|List], Value ) :-
    NextIndex is Index - 1,
    fill( NextIndex, List, Value ).
```

The cut is mandatory to avoid infinite recursion and a fail result.

I tried to modify the rule #2 but after giving the expected solution, goal fails :

```
fill( Index, [Value|List], Value ) :-
    Index > 0,
    NextIndex is Index - 1,
    fill( NextIndex, List, Value ).
```

How it works:

```
?- fill( 7, AllFalse, false ).
AllFalse = [false, false, false, false, false, false, false].

?-
```

Answer (score 0):

```
eq(X, Y) :- X = Y.
fill(N, Xs, V) :-
    length(Xs, N), maplist(eq(V), Xs).
```

While this has no external cuts, `length/2` has them in generative mode.

You are destructuring a integer value, when checking it's value you always create a choicepoint. If there was a natural number mathematically implemented as follows then you can have a deterministic fill predicate.

```
nat(0).
nat(suc(X)) :- nat(X).

fill_nat(0, [], _).
fill_nat(suc(N), [V|Xs], V) :-
    fill_nat(N, Xs, V).

?- fill_nat(suc(suc(suc(0))), Xs, a).
Xs = [a, a, a].
```

Comment: suc? It's not succ, rather?

Comment: your choice, just short for `successor`.

Comment: The first proposal is more complex and hide the cut in the call, it's not a solution.

Comment: I don't think there is a deterministic solution, unless you use something like `nat` above.

Comment: `length/2` doesn't exactly need cuts, since it is a foreign implemented function but non-logical-ness is from it.

Comment: Here is its implementation: https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc/_SWI_/boot/init.pl?show=src#length/2

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224584/discussion-between-rajashekar-and-aubin).

Answer (score 0):

I believe this works correctly:

```
fill(0, [], _).
fill(N, [Val|Tail], Val) :- 
    N > 0,
    N2 is N-1,
    fill(N2, Tail, Val).
```

(This is equivalent to your second version, and without the cut)

```
?- fill(2, X, 33).
X = [33, 33] .

?-
```

> but after giving the expected solution, goal fails

It gives you one solution, and if you want more solutions, then it says "there aren't any".

```
?- fill(2, X, 33).
X = [33, 33] ;
false.

?-
```

Comment: If you trace your code, you will see the backtracking and the fail.

Comment: @Aubin It fails to find **more** solutions. That's why it prints `false`. Why is that a problem?

Comment: @Aubin There's no infinite recursion, and no `!`.

Comment: When using unit testing a warning is displayed about choice point.

Comment: @Aubin The problem's with the test IMO, but I added another alternative. `maplist` is defined in one of my recent questions.

Comment: numlist itself contains a cut.
It's not a solution https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc/_SWI_/library/lists.pl?show=src#numlist/3

Comment: @Aubin same as `length` I think.